# How to build and load shared library on rstudio for package that uses C/C++ files in src folder inside a subdirectory?

Tags: c++, c, r, rstudio, subdirectory

I have a R package that I'm working on that contains code written in C and C++ under the src folder. Currently, the package compiles and works on Rstudio as it follows the default directory structure. As the project builds, I want to be able to organize my code under src, within subfolders. Following directions from "Writing R extensions" - Compiling under sub-directories, I have made a folder called 'test'(/src/test) which now contains all my files(*.c, *.cpp, *.h) and modified my Makevars like so -

```
SOURCES_C = $(wildcard test/*.c)
SOURCES_CPP = $(wildcard test/*.cpp)
PKG_CPPFLAGS= -I${R_HOME}/include -I.
PKG_LIBS = -L${R_HOME}/lib 

CXX_STD = CXX11
OBJECTS =$(SOURCES_CPP:.cpp=.o)  $(SOURCES_C:.c=.o) 

all : $(SHLIB) 
#PKG_CFLAGS= -Wall

clean : rm -f *.o
```

I want to be able to compile the program in this state, where the C/C++ files are under subfolders inside src. Using the aforementioned Makevars -> the separate object files are being built from the test folder with the correct flags and compiler, for all C/CPP files. However, there are some discrepancies with the build command for the shared object. This is the log when compiling the files under src/test which fails with an undefined symbol error.

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o BioCro.so test/BBox.o test/Climate.o test/Compound.o test/Grid.o test/LeafOptics.o test/Maths.o test/Normal.o test/Point3D.o test/Ray.o test/Triangle.o test/Vector3D.o test/runFastTracer.o test/Assigncropcent.o test/AuxBioCro.o test/AuxCropGro.o test/AuxMaizeGro.o test/AuxcaneGro.o test/Auxcropcent.o test/AuxwillowGro.o test/BioCro.o test/CalculateBiogeochem.o test/Calculate_Soil_Layer_Temperature.o test/CanA.o test/CanAC_3D.o test/Century.o test/Copy_CropCent_To_DayCent_Structure.o test/Copy_SoilWater_BioCro_To_CropCent.o test/CropGro.o test/CropGro_c.o test/Filling_BioCro_SoilStructure.o test/assignManagement.o test/c3CanA.o test/c3EvapoTrans.o test/c3photo.o test/c4photo.o test/caneGro.o test/createNULLc3tree.o test/cropcent.o test/dailywillow.o test/denitrify.o test/diffusiv.o test/eC4photo.o test/getIdirIdiff.o test/getsoilprop.o test/leachdly.o test/maizeGro.o test/methane.o test/microclimate_for_3Dcanopy.o test/nitrify.o test/nox_pulse.o test/pi_funcs.o test/printcropcentoutput.o test/test_mainC.o test/tgmodel.o test/tracegas.o test/update_3Dcanopy_structure.o test/wfps.o test/willowCent.o test/willowGro.o -L/usr/local/R-3.1.0/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/local/R-3.1.0/lib64/R/lib -lR

installing to /home/vashist1/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BioCro/

** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/vashist1/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BioCro/libs/BioCro.so':
  /home/vashist1/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BioCro/libs/BioCro.so:
undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
Error: loading failed
```

Compared with the successful log which builds successfully!

```
g++ -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o BioCro.so Assigncropcent.o AuxBioCro.o AuxCropGro.o AuxMaizeGro.o AuxcaneGro.o Auxcropcent.o AuxwillowGro.o BBox.o BioCro.o CalculateBiogeochem.o Calculate_Soil_Layer_Temperature.o CanA.o CanAC_3D.o Century.o Climate.o Compound.o Copy_CropCent_To_DayCent_Structure.o Copy_SoilWater_BioCro_To_CropCent.o CropGro.o CropGro_c.o Filling_BioCro_SoilStructure.o Grid.o LeafOptics.o Maths.o Normal.o Point3D.o Ray.o Triangle.o Vector3D.o assignManagement.o c3CanA.o c3EvapoTrans.o c3photo.o c4photo.o caneGro.o createNULLc3tree.o cropcent.o dailywillow.o denitrify.o diffusiv.o eC4photo.o getIdirIdiff.o getsoilprop.o leachdly.o maizeGro.o methane.o microclimate_for_3Dcanopy.o nitrify.o nox_pulse.o pi_funcs.o printcropcentoutput.o runFastTracer.o test_mainC.o tgmodel.o tracegas.o update_3Dcanopy_structure.o wfps.o willowCent.o willowGro.o -L/usr/local/R-3.1.0/lib64/R/lib -lR

installing to /home/vashist1/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BioCro/libs
```

1) The shared object compiles using g++ under default conditions, whereas under subdirectory conditions the compiler used is gcc. Can I change that behaviour via Makevars?

2) Further research allowed me to find that the undefined symbol error is a linking error fixed by the -L/-l flag. However, the -L flag is the same for both build commands. Is there any other library I am failing to link which is linked by default?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Looking at the example of the RSiena package mentioned as an example in ["Writing R Extensions" section 1.2.1.3](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Compiling-in-sub_002ddirectories) I noticed that that package still has some `.cpp` files not in a subdirectory. So I added a `dummy.cpp` file in `src/` with the following contents:

```
void dummy (void)
{
}
```

After this `g++` was correctly used for the linking step and the `.so` file was created as expected.

---

In my case it turns out that I don't need to change the `Makevars` files as I first mentioned in my answer. Even without the change below (so only having the `dummy.cpp` file present in `src/`) linking is done correctly.
I'll leave it in in case it may help someone else with a (slightly) different setup.

---

And add the corresponding `.o` file in the list of `$(OBJECTS)` variable in the `Makevars` file:

```
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o) dummy.o
```